# Share Image, plain text and html text via Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, share

I'm trying to implement a function to share some information. The app requires to send plain text, HTML-formatted text (links) and a picture. This should be possible through SMS, Gmail, Whatsapp, etc. So far I've tried the following code:

```
    public void shareInfo(){

        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

        // Name (String), Type (String), Direction (String) and Images(String-HTML)
        String text = name+ "<br />";
        text = text + type + "<br />";
        text = text + direction + "<br />";                     

        // Images (String-HTML links)                                   
        for(int cont = 0; cont < _urlThumbsImagenes.length; cont++){
            text = text + "<a href=" + "\'" + _urlThumbsImagenes[cont] + "\'>" + "Image " + cont + "</a>" + "<br />";
        }
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(text));
        shareIntent.setType("text/html");           

        // Image 
        Uri pathImage = (Uri) ivPortada.getTag();
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pathImagenPortada);
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");

        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Intent :D"));
    }
```

This works for me when the Gmail option is chosen, but does not work in any other choice to share. If the user chooses SMS or WhatsApp, only shows the image to send.

**How I can implement the function so that information is shared completely independently of the chosen mode?**

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Activities honoring `ACTION_SEND` are only required to support *either* `EXTRA_TEXT` *or* `EXTRA_STREAM`, not both on the same `Intent`. If you use `EXTRA_TEXT`, the MIME type in the `Intent` should be identifying the MIME type of the value of `EXTRA_TEXT`. If you are using `EXTRA_STREAM`, the MIME type in the `Intent` should be identifying the MIME type of the data pointed to by the `Uri` in `EXTRA_STREAM`.
In your case, your first `setType()` call will be overwritten by the second `setType()` call.

Answer (score 1):

I solved:

```
public static void ShareInfo(Activity activity) {
    // Intent to share info
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    // Info
    String text = name+ "." + System.getProperty("line.separator");
    text = text + type+ "." + System.getProperty("line.separator");
    text = text + adress+ "." + System.getProperty("line.separator");  

    // Image
    Uri pathImagenPortada = (Uri) ivPortada.getTag();

    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);    
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pathImagenPortada);
    shareIntent.setType("image/*"); 


    shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    activity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Intent :D"));   
}
```

This way I can send text and images by virtually any application permitted.

Comment: What is ivPortada